# Connect to POSTgres DB locally from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am running RDS database cluster in a VPC in AWS (AURORA_POSTGRESQL) and would like to access it from a lambda function that runs in the same VPC. My lambdas are also served from an API gateway that has been setup as a RESTful API.

Currently here is what happens:

1. I make an HTTP request to a route in the API gateway
2. The API gateway triggers the corresponding lambda
3. The lambda connects to POSTgres via a public connection string

   `postgresql://postgres:myPassword@my-db-public-endpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres?schema=SCHEMA`

As you can see the above connection string is a public one (can be accessed from anywhere).

I would like to make it private for security reasons, Is it possible to change the connection string in my lambda function to POSTgres to be one local to the VPC? ie something like:

```
postgresql://postgres:myPassword@10.0.0.1:5432/postgres?schema=SCHEMA
```

Not sure if this is best practice, but if it is would love some info on how to achieve this. Have not found much useful info online

Comment: Do you have the "publicly accessible" flag set to `true` on the RDS server?

Comment: yes that right.

Comment: By enabling that flag, you made the endpoint for connecting to the database public. However, I think inside the VPC that address resolves to a private IP address (you should be able to check this from an EC2 instance in the VPC).